# Typescript error when updating local state using useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component that fetches messages and stores them in a local variable using `useState`

```
const [localMessages, setLocalMessages] = useState<Message[]>([])
```

When the component retrieves the messages it stores them in `localMessages` like so

```
  setLocalMessages((prevState) => {
    return [...prevState, ...data.getMessagesForConversation.messages]
  })
```

The get messages query retrieves the list of messages and each message has a `sender` object identifying who sent the message. This is causing a Typescript error when attempting to update `localMessages` with the following error

```
Type '{ __typename?: "Message" | undefined; uuid: string; content: string; updatedAt: string; createdAt: string; type: string; src?: string | null | undefined; deleted: boolean; sender: { __typename?: "Profile" | undefined; uuid: string; username: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Message'.
          Types of property 'sender' are incompatible.
            Type '{ __typename?: "Profile" | undefined; uuid: string; username: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Profile': updatedAt, createdAt, user, friends, friendshipRequests
```

Is there anything else I need to update in the useState declaration to make it identify the sender type?

Message type:

```
export type Message = {
  __typename?: 'Message';
  uuid: Scalars['String'];
  sender: Profile;
  content: Scalars['String'];
  updatedAt: Scalars['String'];
  createdAt: Scalars['String'];
};
```

getMessagesForConversation type:

```
getMessagesForConversation: PaginatedMessages;
```

GetMessagesForConversationQuery type:

```
export type GetMessagesForConversationQuery = { __typename?: 'Query', getMessagesForConversation: { __typename?: 'PaginatedMessages', hasMore: boolean, messages: Array<{ __typename?: 'Message', uuid: string, content: string, updatedAt: string, createdAt: string, type: string, src?: string | null, deleted: boolean, sender: { __typename?: 'Profile', uuid: string, username: string } }> } };
```

Comment: Can you post the Message type code and what type is the messages property on getMessagesForConversation?

Comment: @Poku Sure, just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `GetMessagesForConversationQuery["messages"]["sender"]` type is similar to your branded `Profile` type, but still incomplete:

```
sender: {
  __typename?: 'Profile',
  uuid: string,
  username: string
}
```

...whereas your complete `Profile` type seems to be:

```
{
  __typename?: 'Profile',
  uuid: string,
  username: string,
  updatedAt: ?,
  createdAt: ?,
  user: ?,
  friends: ?,
  friendshipRequests: ?
}
```

You very probably need to define a more limited type.

If you can change the `Message["sender"]` type, you could use e.g. the [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) TypeScript built-in utility type to select only the properties you need (and have `GetMessagesForConversationQuery["messages"]["sender"]` compatible):

```
type Message = {
  __typename?: 'Message';
  uuid: Scalars['String'];
  sender: Pick<Profile, "uuid" | "username">;
  content: Scalars['String'];
  updatedAt: Scalars['String'];
  createdAt: Scalars['String'];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could i ask you to elaborate on what you mean by defining a more limited type?

Comment: You could use `Pick` for example.